# Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ 5G - cellebrite mobile forensics data extractions - locked with pattern

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption, bootloader-lock, samsung-knox

I've got a locked Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ 5G (running the latest android 10 and patches)

The phone is locked with a pattern (unknown)

What are my chances of any data extraction with cellebrite or other forensics tools while I can not unlock the phone?

Also how secure is Knox efuse? will it damage the phone/data when an untrusted bootloader is detected?

Comment: The chance that you meet meet here someone who has (access to) a Cellebrite system and can answer your question is very low as these are expensive professional systems. Why don't you ask Cellebrite? They should know what is possible.

Comment: chances: [zero](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227110) knox: [impossible](https://youtu.be/cTltHuEjTM8)