# Redmi Note 8 locked, need help with unlocking/backup

Tags: adb, backup, lock-screens, xiaomi, locked-out

I need help regarding a Redmi Note 8 that no longer accepts the correct pattern and is locked.

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to either unlock my phone without data loss, or make a backup of the phone's internal storage on an sd card/pc before hard resetting.

The device is not rooted and I don't have custom recovery installed. USB Debugging is on, but my laptop is not authorized. Bootloader is locked.

With Adb, the device is detected but unauthorized. It seems to be detected normally in fastboot mode. I was able to get my laptop to detect it in recovery mode by clicking on "Connect with MIAssistant" while it was plugged in, but only in sideload mode. I also somehow managed to get into safe mode, but I used the stock screen lock, so unless there's something else that can be done in that mode, it doesn't seem useful in this situation.

I tried the actual MIAssistant software but it tells me to update my device before connecting. From what I found, this is because it doesn't even work with phones running Android 6.0 Marshmallow or above, so that seems to be a dead-end, unfortunately. Downloaded from [here](http://pcsuite.mi.com/), updated to version 3.2.1.3111. If there's a newer version that could support my device, even an untranslated one, I would love to know, but I couldn't find a working one.

I had some ideas that could potentially solve my problem, but couldn't find a way to actually execute them, so here they are in case someone out there who knows more than me could help me with one of them.

1, Is there any way I could authorize my laptop for USB Debugging without being able to accept the prompt on screen?

2, Is there a way to make a backup of the internal storage of my phone in fastboot/sideload mode?

3, Is there a way to get adb to detect this device normally in recovery mode, instead of in sideload mode?

4, Is there a way to get my device into mtp/ptp mode instead of charging mode when connected to a PC without USB Debugging so I can copy my files?

5, [Here's a thread I found that seems promising, although it's old.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/no-root-no-usb-debugging-unlock-your-android-pattern.2308130/) Could I somehow use this, or a similar method on Redmi Note 8? The Recovery Mode is much more limiting on this device, unfortunately, so I can't exactly follow this tutorial. Are there alternatives that can be done in adb fastboot/sideload mode, perhaps?

6, I have tried following [these instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/enable-usb-debugging-on-locked-phone.3747581/#post-77816992), but after step 8, I got the message `FAILED (remote: Fastboot boot command is not available in locked device)`. I assume this mean this method no longer works on a locked bootlocker. Is there a workaround for this?

7, If I am forced to hard reset, is there any method or software out there that could recover at least some of the deleted data afterwards, or is everything lost in case of a reset?

I am open to new ideas not listed above, as well. I am not a very advanced user so I probably missed some things.

Thank you so much for any answer in advance!

Comment: On a device with locked bootloader, standard recovery, no adb access and a lock screen that can't be passed it is next to impossible to get access to the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover data when everything is locked (FRP, OEM)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227110/how-to-recover-data-when-everything-is-locked-frp-oem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering data from Mi 4c able to get only to fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/recovering-data-from-mi-4c-able-to-get-only-to-fastboot)

Comment: This device runs new F2FS file system which is failure-prone. Furthermore files are encrypted with FBE file-based encryption, this is worst case for data recovery. However, if your data is worth it, pay for professional data recovery, some expert may by-pass signature verification and flash TWRP recovery from EDL mode [proof of concept](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3772381) (assuming you know correct pattern). In any case don't do factory reset

Comment: Thank you so much for the resources. I will try to contact a professional and see if there's anything they can do.